# Get Contents Url Of Ajax by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, curl

http://xemtv.tv/live/itv?ajax=1&t=B616346DA110F6B7FCF2C1F17D8C9004F8414A604869CE9FC226C62C626A29AC&server=1

I want get contents this link by php, i have used cUrl, file_get_contents not working. Error:

```js
{
error: true,
data: "token"
}
```

I want get:

```js
{
type: "iframe",
url: "http://xemtv.tv/iframe/player?stream=aHR0cDovL3hlbXR2LnR2L3JlYWRlci9mcHQvaXR2L3R0eTR5YmpZOXZIb2RDcjFYODd3OSt2aXdGZjdrMDdfT2cvcGxheWxpc3QubTN1OA==&type=hls&player=yeah1",
width: 720,
height: 400,
attrs: [ ]
}
```

Want to get the content you have load the link before, I continually get this link content.

Comment: Probably a configuration problem with your server

Comment: When I go to that URL in the browser, I get the same error response. It's not a problem in your code, that's what the server returns.

Comment: You ip is block, you try after 5 min.